# Draggable and swipable container in flutter

Tags: user-interface, animation, flutter

I'm new to flutter and I'm looking for a way to implement a simple feature. A draggable container.

I have two groups of UI elements wrapped in a `Container` widget. I want to be able to go from one group to another by dragging or swiping in different directions.

**How would I go about doing this?**

Here are sample images of my UI design to help you understand what I want to achieve:

Image #1

[image: Tab 1]

Image #2

[image: Tab 2]

As you can see, Image #1 and Image #2 are only different in the bottom part of my design. I have already created all the necessary UI elements and wrapped them in the `Container` widget. Now the only thing I need is the ability to go from one group to another. It would also be nice if there was a callback method that could update the buttons above upon transitioning from one group to another.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities to achieve this, depends on your exact wishes, here are 3 ideas:

1. Using a TabBarView to swipe the entire screen, Tab1 will be the first screen you showed, and Tab2 will be second screen - only the contents. (you probably did not want that, but just putting it out there).
2. Dividing the container into 2 pieces (vertically), and placing the TabBarView on the bottom part, having 2 tabs: 1 with the Today part and one with the Weekly part. (there are a few examples out there, for instance: [divide screen into two equal parts in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54919882/divide-screen-into-two-equal-parts-in-flutter)).

You can also customize the build method to change anything (for example the top indicator) based on the current tab index (as asked and answered here: [How to get current tab index in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123354/how-to-get-current-tab-index-in-flutter))

For a more custom solution you can use:

3. GestureDetector wrapped around your container, and handle OnHorizontalDragX (where X is Start, End etc.) to do any custom stuff - maybe changing the state and trigger a rebuild with the new image

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for!