# I want two list view with same area in single screen, how can I set it up?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, listview

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Demo Project")),
      body: new Padding(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new ListView(children: getDemolist()),
            new ListView(children: getDemolisttwo())
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

All two list view will display in same area in responsive way.

Answer (score 5):

Use **Flexible** and you can change **flex property** in it, just like **Expanded**.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(child: getDemolist()),
    Flexible(child: getDemolisttwo()),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Mediaquery is an alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54919882/divide-screen-into-two-equal-parts-in-flutter

Comment: yes, of course. but the use of Flexible & Expanded is a more efficient way.